# Trying to import an Excel table into an existing SharePoint List, but having difficulties

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, excel, flow, powerapp

So I have a SharePoint List that contains a column that holds a special ID. Let's call it orderNumber. Then I have 2 other columns (lets call one Car and the other Color).

Now, both these columns are empty but the orderNumber column already contains numbers. Now my Excel table contains the data that needs to be placed in the car and color columns.

So, for example, in my SharePoint list lets say 1 is in the orderNumber. In the Excel table, we have three columns (orderNumer, car, color) and it would contain 1, ford, red.

I am attempting to populate the fields in the SharePoint list with this correlating data, but I am having difficulty. I created a Flow but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.
[image]

Comment: Are you getting any error? or execution flow is not going in **If yes** block?

Comment: no error, the flow just runs for a very long time and nothing happens. I usually end up canceling it. I believe it isn't going into the if yes block

Comment: If it's running for too long without any errors, it might be a throttling issue. Do you have any other flows running in your tenant with your account? There is a limit of 2000 flow actions per 24 hours period for office 365 account.

Answer (score 0):

Updating existing SharePoint lists from Excel is a frequent topic, and there is no satisfying out of the box solution other than coding. I don't understand why your flow doesn't work.

My company offers a simple (and quite affordable) software to do that, [Synchronizer for Excel and SharePoint](https://www.synchronizer-for-excel-and-sharepoint.com/). It lets you open an existing SharePoint list from Excel, modify it in Excel and send your changes back to SharePoint. Works with any version of SharePoint and any versions of Excel running on Windows.

If you need to do it only once, you can even do it for free with the trial version.